# Should exceptions be used to describe user input errors?

Tags: java, exception

I have a service that saves a tree-like structure to a database. Before persisting the tree, the tree gets validated, and during validation, a number of things can go wrong. The tree can have duplicate nodes, or a node can be missing an important field (such as its abbreviation, full name, or level).

In order to communicate to the service what went wrong, I'm using exceptions. When the validateTree() method encounters a problem, it throws the appropriate exception. The HttpService class then uses this exception to form the appropriate response (e.g. in response to an AJAX call).

```
public class HttpService {

    private Service service;
    private Logger logger;

    // ...

    public HttpServiceResponse saveTree(Node root) {
        try {
            service.saveTree(root);  
        } catch (DuplicateNodeException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(DUPLICATE_NODE);
        } catch (MissingAbbreviationException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_ABBREV);
        } catch (MissingNameException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_NAME);
        } catch (MissingLevelException e) {
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(MISSING_LEVEL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(e.getMessage(), e. Logger.ERROR);
            return HttpServiceResponse.failure(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

public class Service {

    private TreeDao dao;

    public void saveTree(Node root) 
        throws DuplicateNodeException, MissingAbbreviationException, MissingNameException, MissingLevelException {

        validateTree(root);
        dao.saveTree(root);
    }

    private void validateTree(Node root) 
        throws DuplicateNodeException, MissingAbbreviationException, MissingNameException, MissingLevelException {

        // validate and throw checked exceptions if needed
    }
}
```

I want to know, is this a good use of exceptions? Essentially, I'm using them to convey error messages. An alternative would be for my saveTree() method to return an integer, and that integer would convey the error. But in order to do this, I would have to document what each return value means. That seems to be more in the style of C/C++ than Java. Is my current use of exceptions a good practice in Java? If not, what's the best alternative?

Comment: I would say that you have quite a few exceptions. Maybe, you can reduce them and have an `error code` within the exception class to denote what the problem was. But, it depends on what the caller could (and can) do if it encounters an exception

Comment: It looks like some of these exception types can be consolidated.  All of the `Missing*Exception`s look like they'd all qualify for HTTP 400 (Bad Request), and could be consolidated into a `MissingDataException` with a message saying exactly what is missing.

Comment: Adding to @JoeC's comment, how nice does the service have to be?  This is from a security perspective where trusted users should already know what a good request looks like - it is their responsibility to provide a valid request.  Compare that to a hacker which is trying to figure out the expected payload based on the nice error messages.  A basic HTTP 400 with no additional info is more secure, and simplifies the service.

Comment: About 404 http https://www.nngroup.com/articles/improving-dreaded-404-error-message/

Answer (score 1):

No, exceptions aren't a good fit for the validation you need to do here. You will likely want to display multiple validation error messages, so that the user can see all the validation errors at once, and throwing a separate exception for each invalid input won't allow that.

Instead create a list and put errors in it. Then you can show the user the list of all the validation errors.

Waiting until your request has gotten all the way to the DAO seems like the wrong time to do this validation. A server-side front controller should be doing validation on these items before they get passed along any farther, as protection against attacks such as injection or cross-site scripting.

Comment: I actually don't want to display multiple validation errors at once. We are currently displaying validation errors in a popup, and displaying two or more would create a very long popup. Not to mention there could easily be a dozen errors in the tree, which would be impossible to display in a popup. I would rather display one error at a time, based on the priority of the error.  Considering this requirement, what would be a good alternative to the Exception-based system I am using?

Comment: @ktm5124: at least this way you have all the information so in case you want to change you can.  Also you should validate up front as defense against injection and xss attacks.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR The Java-side parts you showed us are nearly perfect. But you could add an independent validation check and use that from the client side before trying to save.**

There are many software layers involved, so let's have a look at each of them - there's no "one size fits all" answer here.

- For the `Service` object, it's the perfect solution to have it throw exceptions from the `saveTree()` method if it wasn't able to save the tree (for whatever reason, not limited to validation). That's what exceptions are meant for: to communicate that some method couldn't do its job. And the `Service` object shouldn't rely on some external validation, but make sure itself that only valid data are saved.
- The `HttpService.saveTree()` should also communicate to its caller if it couldn't save the tree (typically indicated by an exception from the `Service`). But as it's an HTTP service, it can't throw exceptions, but has to return a result code plus a text message, just the way you do it. This can never contain the full information from the Java exception, so it's a good decision that you log any unclear errors here (but you should make sure that the stack trace gets logged too!), before you pass an error result to the HTTP client.
- The web client UI software should of course present detailed error lists to the user and not just a translated single exception. So, I'd create an `HttpService.validateTree(...)` method that returns a list of validation errors and call that from the client before trying to save. This gives you the additional possibility to check for validity independent of saving.

Why do it this way?

- You never have control what happens in the client, inside some browser, you don't even know whether the request is coming from your app or from something like `curl`. So you can't rely on any validation that your JavaScript (?) application might implement. All of your service methods should reject invalid data, by doing the validation themselves.
- Implementing the validation checks in a JavaScript client application still needs the same validation inside the Java service (see above), so you'd have to maintain two pieces of code in different languages doing exactly the same business logic - don't repeat yourself! Only if the additional roundtrip isn't tolerable, then I'd regard this an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Visible and highly noticeable**, both in terms of the message itself and how it indicates which dialogue element users must repair.

From Guru Nielsen,
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/